# Why would a raccoon hold its ground in the middle of the road with oncoming traffic?

Tags: united-states, animals, raccoons

[image]

I was driving on a suburban road at night when I noticed an animal at a distance in the middle of the road. As I approached, I was able to see it was a raccoon. I stopped.

It was just standing in the middle of road. It wasn't eating. It didn't appear injured. It wasn't doing anything. Just standing there.

I blew the horn. It was startled but wouldn't budge. I flashed the high beams. Nothing. I lunged the car forward. Nothing. It just held its ground.

Driving at night in these parts I frequently encounter deer, opossums, rabbits, foxes and raccoons. They all run to safety as the vehicle approaches. This particular raccoon behaved differently.

What would possess a small animal to hold its ground as a giant object barrels towards it?

video of the incident:
https://youtu.be/SUvHnoqOQfc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What would possess a small animal to hold its ground as a giant object barrels towards it?

Some kind of illness or injury. The racoon in your video did not appear to be injured.

The raccoon's behavior in your video is far from normal. If you live in an area where racoon rabies is found (it's particularly bad in the eastern and southern states in the US), it's probably rabies or another serious virus (parvovirus or distemper.)

> Behavioral change is one of earliest signs of rabies in raccoons. Acting in a way that is contrary to the norm is an indication of rabies. These changes include being too aggressive... ...more friendly and easy to tame ...[L]ooks [C]onfused and [S]low... ...the raccoon is walking in circles and its movements seem to have no purpose... A healthy raccoon always stays alert and does things purposefully.

Decades ago, I saw a rabid dog in a busy intersection, where it had stopped traffic. It was unmistakable: the dog was lunging at cars, foaming at the mouth, acting wildly inappropriately. But not all animals with rabies act like that stereotype. Bats don't necessarily look sick at all. Relatively early in the course, raccoons may simply appear disoriented.

Injured animals tend to be still even in inappropriately unsafe spaces. A juvenile oppossum was crouching under a neighbor's car in daylight, unmoving. The neighbor brought it to me. I thought it was just lost, but it didn't resist me in any way (nor was it aggressive.) On careful examination, it had two puncture wounds, one on either side of it's chest, and one was deep enough to have punctured it's lung (it had subcutaneous emphysema.) I was worried that it would be euthanized if turned over to a wildlife facility, so it was nursed back to health in my bathroom. Luckily, it didn't take to this human and was released uneventfully. I've seen injured rabbits and birds behave similarly depending somewhat on the injury.

<sub>[How to Tell If a Raccoon Has Rabies](https://www.animalcapturewildlifecontrol.com/blog/how-to-tell-if-a-raccoon-has-rabies/)</sub>.

<sub>[Raccoons and public health](https://www.humanesociety.org/resources/raccoons-and-public-health)</sub>

Comment: How is this the correct answer? It's an answer, but the more likely reason is memorization as indicated by the other answer with more than double the score.

Comment: @Escoce - Votes, bah, seriously. If you are familiar with raccoons in suburbia (the user with the older answer is not: there are no raccoons where they live), you would know that raccoons don't freeze in headlights. Deer do. I've never seen an uninjured rabbit freeze in headlights. I don't know what moose, elk, bison and a great many other animals do. But I know what cats, dogs, deer, rabbits, birds (yes, in the road, eating road kill), opossums, coyotes, foxes, goats/donkeys/horses (roaming free in other states/countries), sheep and especially raccoons do.

Comment: @Escoce, I grew up with racccoons all around me. I know a lot about them just from experience. The older answer, despite the upvotes, doesn't align with my experience. I've explained why in my comments to that answer. This particular raccoon, in my view, has a disease (most likely rabies). This answer is the most on target at this point.

Comment: @MichaelBenjamin - I just googled do raccoons freeze in headlights, and this was the first hit (chuckling bc of how different this advice is from prior answer): "Headlights can also blind animals such as coyotes, raccoons, opossums, and cougars. If an animal “freezes” in your headlights, slow down and blink the lights on and off. Honk your horn repeatedly. Most important, reduce speed, and be ready to stop." It doesn't say they freeze, though. It's mostly about deer freezing. Still haven't found support for raccoons freezing or ambling kind of aimlessly.

Answer (score 8):

In UK rabbits exhibit this behaviour (no raccoons here). They become mesmerised by the headlights. It's not so much an act of defiance but confusion. There are even idioms (from [Farlex](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/rabbit+in+the+headlights))

> - like a rabbit caught in the headlights
> - like a deer caught in the headlights
>
> If someone is like a rabbit caught in the headlights or like a deer caught in the headlights, they are so frightened or nervous that they do not know what to do.

Sounding the horn will only frighten it more.
This knowledge can be used by hunters. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spotlighting) says

> **Spotlighting** or **lamping** (also known as **jacklighting**, **shining**, **illuminating**, **pit-lamping**, and the **killing lamp**) is a method of hunting nocturnal animals using off-road vehicles and high-powered lights, spotlights, lamps or flashlights, that makes special use of the eyeshine revealed by many animal species. A further important aspect is that many animals (e.g. foxes and rabbits) often remain to continually stare at the light and do not appear to see the light as a threat as they normally would view a human. It is possible to carefully approach animals on foot to a short distance if the bright light is continuously maintained on the animal to greatly improve chances of successful killing. Spotlighting may also be used as a method of surveying nocturnal fauna. Repeated, frequent spotlighting may have a detrimental effect on animals and is discouraged.

I suggest that instead of being aggressive towards the tiny creature ("Get out of my way") you douse the lights, and give it an opportunity to escape.

Perhaps they don't move away so easily, see [When the road is blocked by animals, what's the proper way to proceed?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/153203/62763)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think the theory is plausible, but there are a few items that may not fit: (1) The racoon was in that space before I arrived. I noticed its silhouette from about 100 yards away. It didn't move as the car approached with lights blaring. (2) It didn't appear stunned and wasn't staring at the lights. It was just slow moving and seemingly unconcerned. (3) I've seen animals in the "deer in the headlights" situation. Once they come to, they sprint away. This one slowly ambled to the side. Again, not a care in the world.

Comment: My guess is that it was sick, perhaps in an advanced stage of disease.

Comment: Try to see it from the raccoon's view. It's on this weirdly hard and exposed ground, and two bright lights approach from a distance. The creature is already outside of its comfort zone, and the approaching lights are totally outside of its experience. WTF is all this? Don't expect rational behaviour from it. You've already made it worse by flashing the lights and blaring the horn.

Comment: If it isn't mesmerised, don't expect it to know anything about American ways of fronting.

Comment: You've changed the narrative from the question, which portrays a petrified animal "holding its ground", not as you now say, *"slow moving and unconcerned ... ambled to the side ... not a care in the world."*

Comment: I didn't say it was petrified. Just holding its ground, which it was, until it eventually walked to the side of the car. You can see all this in the video.

Comment: With regard to your first comment, the raccoons here are familiar with roads and headlights. We both live in the same area. But not meaning to argue with you, just adding context. Thanks for taking the time to post an answer.

Comment: @WeatherVane [American ways of fronting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Th-fronting)?  Animals in Norf America are confused? I don't expect raccoons to know about this, and neither do I, but maybe I'm just as confused :-)

Comment: Not addressing your answer, but rather your first comment: raccoons in a suburban roadway are not in a strange environment (outside of its comfort zone). They are very familiar with roads, and are one of the animals that eat roadkill at night, so roads are a common feeding ground, as are garbage cans, backyards, chicken coops (ask me how I know this! Oy!), freshly dug up soil (earthworms, yum), even attics (yes, ask me how I know this, too... that's what you get for having a house in the middle of the woods where I live(d).)

Comment: @MichaelBenjamin if you already knew this, then you self-answered your own question. The animal was sick or dying. I sometimes see this with rabbits when walking in the country (UK) who don't run away when I get near, they just sit there and they are not feeding either.

Comment: @WeatherVane, I did not know this. And I do not know this. It's just a theory from a layperson who lives in the area. I came here looking for more informed answers. Actually, your rabbit comparison would make for a useful answer IMO. The cross-over to raccoons makes logical sense.

Comment: @MichaelBenjamin thanks, but the accepted answer seems to cover this angle.